# How to populate a field using three columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am looking to build a function in SQL Server 2012. I want to populate `Country` based on three columns as country, city and office in sequence. For example, if code find country is available, put country in proper case. If country is blank or null go to city and find country of that city and put country. If country and city both are null or blank then go to office and calculate Country. I am using below code but its not working.

Output in yellow:

[image]

Code:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[CONTRACT_COUNTRY_vk]
    (@COUNTRY NVARCHAR(30),
     @CITY NVARCHAR(60),
     @OFFICE NVARCHAR(60))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(30)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @CONTRACT_COUNTRY NVARCHAR(30)
    DECLARE @CITY NVARCHAR(60)
    DECLARE @OFF NVARCHAR(60)

    IF (@COUNTRY = 'United Kingdom' )
       SET @COUNTRY = 'UK'
    ELSE IF (@COUNTRY = 'GERMANY' )
       SET @COUNTRY = 'Germany'
    ELSE IF (@COUNTRY = 'SWITZERLAND' )
       SET @COUNTRY = 'Switzerland'
    ELSE IF (@COUNTRY IN ('ABC', 'DEFAULT ORGANIZATION'))
       SET @COUNTRY ='Unknown'
    ELSE 
       SET @COUNTRY = @COUNTRY

    SET @CONTRACT_COUNTRY = @COUNTRY

If (@COUNTRY IS NULL OR @COUNTRY = 'Blank') 
begin
--SET @CITY = @CITY 
SET @CONTRACT_COUNTRY = 
(case WHEN ( @CITY = 'AMSTERDAM' ) THEN 'Netherlands'
WHEN ( @CITY = 'HANNOVER' ) THEN 'Germany'
WHEN ( @CITY = 'Hanover' ) THEN 'Germany'
ELSE 'UNKNOWN' END)

If (@COUNTRY = 'Blank' or @COUNTRY IS NULL ) and (@CITY = 'Blank' or @CITY 
IS NULL)
begin
SET @OFF = @OFFICE 
SET @CONTRACT_COUNTRY = 
(CASE   
WHEN ( @OFF = 'Viena') THEN 'Austria'
WHEN ( @OFF = 'LYON') THEN 'France'
ELSE 'UNKNOWN'
END)
END
END
RETURN(@CONTRACT_COUNTRY)
END
```

This code is not calculating correctly.

Comment: Hi, Please help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I modified what you have and got it to work. You don't need to declare city and office variables inside of the function. Those values are already being passed in. You can use them to determine `@CONTRACT_COUNTRY`

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[CONTRACT_COUNTRY_vk]
    (@COUNTRY NVARCHAR(30),
     @CITY NVARCHAR(60),
     @OFFICE NVARCHAR(60))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(30)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @CONTRACT_COUNTRY NVARCHAR(30)
    --Check to see if @COUNTRY is null or 'blank'
    --If not, determine @CONTRACT_COUNTRY based on 
    --CASE statement using @COUNTRY value
    IF (@COUNTRY IS NOT NULL OR @COUNTRY <> 'Blank') 
    BEGIN
        SET @CONTRACT_COUNTRY = (CASE WHEN @COUNTRY = 'United Kingdom' THEN 'UK'
                                WHEN  @COUNTRY = 'GERMANY' THEN 'Germany'
                                WHEN  @COUNTRY = 'SWITZERLAND'  THEN 'Switzerland'
                                ELSE 'UNKNOWN' END)
    END
    --When @COUNTRY is null or 'blank', then use this logic
    IF (@COUNTRY IS NULL OR @COUNTRY = 'Blank') 
    BEGIN
        --Check to see if @CITY is null
        --If so, determine @CONTRACT_COUNTRY based on 
        --CASE statement using @OFFICE value
        IF (@CITY IS NULL OR @CITY = 'Blank')
        BEGIN
            SET @CONTRACT_COUNTRY = (CASE WHEN @OFFICE = 'Vienna' THEN 'Austria'
                                    WHEN  @OFFICE = 'HANNOVER' THEN 'Germany'
                                    WHEN  @OFFICE = 'LYON'  THEN 'France'
                                    ELSE 'UNKNOWN' END)
        END
        --When @CITY is NOT null, then use this logic
        --Determine @CONTRACT_COUNTRY based on 
        --CASE statement using @CITY value
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @CONTRACT_COUNTRY = (CASE WHEN @CITY = 'AMSTERDAM' THEN 'Netherlands'
                                    WHEN  @CITY = 'HANNOVER' THEN 'Germany'
                                    WHEN  @CITY = 'Hannover'  THEN 'Germany'
                                    ELSE 'UNKNOWN' END)
        END
    END    
    RETURN(@CONTRACT_COUNTRY)
END
```

This is what I used to test the scenarios you provided.

```
SELECT dbo.CONTRACT_COUNTRY_vk('United Kingdom' ,'London','London') 'Contract_Country'
UNION ALL
SELECT dbo.CONTRACT_COUNTRY_vk('GERMANY' ,'Berlin','Blank')
UNION ALL
SELECT dbo.CONTRACT_COUNTRY_vk('Switzerland' ,'Berne','Blank')
UNION ALL
SELECT dbo.CONTRACT_COUNTRY_vk('Blank' ,'Blank','LYON')
UNION ALL
SELECT dbo.CONTRACT_COUNTRY_vk('Blank' ,'HANNOVER','Blank')
UNION ALL
SELECT dbo.CONTRACT_COUNTRY_vk('Blank' ,'Blank','Blank')
```

Results

```
+-----------------+
|Contract_Country |
+-----------------+
|   UK            |
|   Germany       |
|   Switzerland   |
|   France        |
|   Germany       |
|   UNKNOWN       |
+-----------------+
```